# AngularJS, clear text when clicking in field NOT using button

Tags: angularjs

I am completely new to AngularJS and was wondering what's the proper way to clear text from my amount field?

I have a default 0.00 set in the field but I want the functionality of when a user clicks in the field the 0.00 disappears.

Ideally I would like this functionality to only work for the default value but either way i'm not bothered if it removes the new value added.

I have tried Googling and the only results I can find are for a clear button set to the field which I don't want.

Right now my HTML is:

```
<number-only-input input-value="transferitems.cashvalue" input-name="cashvalueinput" />
```

And my controller scope is:

```
$scope.totaltransfervalue = 0.00;
```

I need to apply this functionality to 4 others amount fields on the page also.

My directive for the number-only-input is:

```
    app.directive('numberOnlyInput', function ($filter) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',           
        template: '<input name="{{inputName}}" ng-model="inputValue" ng-blur="oninputblur()" style="width:100% !important" class="form-control" required />',
        scope: {
            inputValue: '=',
            inputName: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {               
            scope.oninputblur= function() {
                scope.inputValue = $filter('currency')(scope.inputValue, '', 2);                     
            }                
            scope.$watch('inputValue', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue == oldValue) { return; }
                if (!newValue) {
                    scope.inputValue = "";
                } else {
                    var arr = String(newValue).split("");
                    if (arr.length === 0) return;
                    if (arr.length === 1 && (arr[0] == '-' || arr[0] === '.')) return;
                    if (arr.length === 2 && newValue === '-.') return;
                    if (isNaN(newValue)) {
                        scope.inputValue = oldValue;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Maybe `placeholder="0.00"` is what you're looking for? It will disappear when the user starts typing.

Comment: @AndreasArgelius Thanks for the reply, I tried adding this but it didn't work.  Please see my updated HTML.  I had copied the wrong field in it.  the field is an number-only-input but I can not add the placeholder to it due to the input-value, or am I missing something

Comment: It should work fine. Just add `placeholder` attribute to the input tag. Is `<number-only-input>` a directive you've created yourself? It was a normal `<input>` before your edit, right?

Comment: @AndreasArgelius yes it was but by just adding a placeholder it doesn't work as I tried this before my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Sounds like a job for the HTML `placeholder` attribute</strike>

```
<input placeholder="{{totalTransferValue}}" input-value="transferitems.cashvalue" input-name="cashvalueinput" />
```

It displays the current value of the scope variable as dimmed content which disappears when user start typing in the box. This is not limited to the default value.
No longer relevant since the question has been radically changed.

You should be able to achieve what you want by tweaking the directive itself.

First, you need to add `ng-focus` to the template

```
template: '<input ng-focus="oninputfocus()" ...
```

Then implement the handler

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {               
    scope.oninputfocus = function(){
        // if(scope.inputValue == myDefaultValue) {
        scope.inputValue = '';
        // }
    },
    scope.oninputblur= ...
```

And you should be all set. I included (as comment) how the check to only clear the default value from the field.

Comment: `<input placeholder="{{ totaltransfervalue  }}" input-val...`

Comment: @KalhanoToressPamuditha please see my updated HTML.  I had copied the wrong field in it.  the field is an number-only-input but I can not add the placeholder to it due to the input-value, or am I missing something

Comment: @Alex Thanks for the reply, I tried adding this but it didn't work. Please see my updated HTML. I had copied the wrong field in it. the field is an number-only-input but I can not add the placeholder to it due to the input-value, or am I missing something

Comment: what is the `number-only-input` directive. please post the codes

Comment: @KalhanoToressPamuditha Please see my directive in my initial post above. Hope this helps.

Comment: `template: '<input name="{{inputName}}" placeholder="{{ inputPlaceholder }}" ng-model="inputValue" ng-blu...` change the template in the directive as above and check :)

Comment: and add this also `<number-only-input input-placeholder="{{totalTransferValue}}" input-value="transferitems.cashvalue" `

Comment: Also note that this will only work if transferitems.cashvalue lacks a value from the start. A html5 placeholder is only shown when a field lacks a value, so make sure cashvalue is undefined from the start. Also, placeholder does not work in IE9 and below, but there are fixes for that.

Comment: Answer changed to reflect the current revision of the question. You all probably should clean the comments.